# Перехват события submit

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, возможно ли перехватить событие submit для отмены действия браузера по умолчанию?

```
<form action="" id="test-form"></form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('test-form').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: onsubmit="скрипт" в форме используйте кратко и быстро

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите перехватить событие которое сами инициировали? Вам же не пользователь кликнул на кнопку, а Вы сами запустили отправку формы. Напишите функцию отправки и сделайте в ней все необходимые действия, а в конце отправьте форму.

Comment: Я имитирую отправку формы ботом. Хочу перехватить событие и отменить действие по умолчанию, если это был бот. С обработкой клика проще 
(e.isTrigger || (e.originalEvent && !e.originalEvent.isTrusted) || !e.clientX) && e.preventDefault();

Comment: То есть что бы форма отправлялась только при клике реальным пользователем и блокировалась при машинном .click()?

Comment: В том то и дело, что .click() можно перехватить, я не могу понять, как перехватить .submit()

Comment: Для того, чтобы устранить бота придумана captcha. Без captcha я возьму вашу форму, выброшу все ваши javascript-проверки на бота, и скормлю форму боту в чистом виде. И он (бот) вам наваляет!

Answer (score 0):

Пример.

```js
function submitFn() {
  console.log(`submit time: ${new Date()}`)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitFn();return false">
  <div>
    форма ....
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Не будет работать. Попробуйте инициировать событие form.submit(); чтобы проверить попадаете ли вы в функцию submitFn()

Comment: Ну так, нажмите воспроизвести код и нажмите кнопку submit

Comment: В вашем примере сперва идет событие click, которое инициирует submit. Click я могу перехватить и отменить если мне нужно. Сделовательно, событие submit не произойдет. Я же говорю о другой ситуации и не зря в вопросе разместил код document.getElementById('test-form').submit();. Мне нужно перехватить событие submit, которое было инициализировано с помощью триггера.

Comment: Или я понять не могу или так написали: "перехватить событие submit для отмены действия браузера" В моем примере при сабмите переход не происходит. Выполняется функция которая выводит данные в консоль.

Comment: Нужно перехватить событие submit, которое было инициировано триггером document.getElementById('test-form').submit();